# Update component when the store changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to update a component based on store updates, the objective of that is, when I click on a table item, I want to update the form buttons to edit form, and Edit the table item.

[image]

[image]

My source code:

I have an action which updates `currentUser`. `currentUser` is the user I want to update

***src/actions/user.js***

```
export const updateCurrentUserSuccess = (currentUser) => {
    return {
        type: UPDATE_CURRENT_USER,
        currentUser
    }
}

export const updateCurrentUser = (id) => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        return axios.get(`${apiUrl}/users/${id}`)
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response.data.data)
                dispatch(updateCurrentUserSuccess(response.data.data))
            })
            .catch(error => {
                throw (error);
            });
    };
};
```

my currentUserReducer:
***src/reducers/currentUserReducer.js***

```
import { UPDATE_CURRENT_USER } from '../constants/ActionTypes';

const initialState = {
    currentUser: [],
}

export default function userReducer(state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case UPDATE_CURRENT_USER:
            return action.currentUser;
        default: 
            return state;
    }
}
```

now my components:

my NewUser form:
***src/components/NewUser.js***

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import { Store } from '../store'

    class NewUser extends Component {
        state = {
            id: '',
            name: '',
            cpfcnpj: '',
            isEdit: false
        };

        componentDidMount(){
            this.handleUserChange()
        }

        handleInputChange = e => {
            this.handleUserChange();
            this.setState({
                [e.target.name]: e.target.value
            });
        };

        handleSubmit = e => {
            e.preventDefault();
            if (!this.state.isEdit) {
                if (this.state.name.trim() && this.state.cpfcnpj.trim()) {
                    this.props.onAddUser(this.state);
                    this.handleReset();
                }
            } else {
                if (this.state.name.trim() && this.state.cpfcnpj.trim() && this.state.id !== '') {
                    this.props.onEdit(this.state);
                    this.handleReset();
                }
            }

        };

        handleReset = () => {
            Store.getState().currentUser = []
            this.setState({
                id: '',
                name: '',
                cpfcnpj: '',
                isEdit: false
            });
        };

        handleUserChange() {
            console.log('store', Store.getState().currentUser._id);
            if (Store.getState().currentUser._id !== undefined) {
                this.setState({
                    id: Store.getState().currentUser._id,
                    name: Store.getState().currentUser.name,
                    cpfcnpj: Store.getState().currentUser.cpfcnpj,
                    isEdit: true
                });
            }
        }

        render() {
            return (
                <div>
                    <form className="form-inline" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                        <div className="form-group margin-right">
                            <input
                                type="text"
                                placeholder="Name"
                                className="form-control"
                                name="name"
                                onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                                value={this.state.name}
                            />
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group margin-right">
                            <input
                                type="text"
                                placeholder="CPF/CNPJ"
                                className="form-control"
                                name="cpfcnpj"
                                onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                                value={this.state.cpfcnpj}>
                            </input>
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <button type="submit" className={this.state.isEdit ? "btn btn-success margin-right hidden" : "btn btn-success margin-right"}>
                                <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                &nbsp;
                                Adicionar
                            </button>
                            <button type="submit" className={this.state.isEdit ? "btn btn-primary margin-right" : "btn btn-primary margin-right hidden"}>
                                <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                &nbsp;
                                Salvar
                            </button>
                            <button type="button" className="btn btn-default margin-right" onClick={this.handleReset}>
                                <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-erase" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                &nbsp;
                                Limpar
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            );
        }
    }

    export default NewUser;

my component User item:
***src/components/User.js***

import React from 'react';

export default ({ user: { name, cpfcnpj, _id }, onDelete, onEditUser }) => {
    return (
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">{name}</th>
            <td>{cpfcnpj}</td>
            <td>
                <button className="btn btn-warning btn-xs margin-right" type="button" onClick={() => onEditUser(_id)}>
                    <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" aria-hidden="true"> </span>
                    &nbsp;
                    Editar
                </button>
                <button className="btn btn-danger btn-xs margin-right" type="button" onClick={() => onDelete(_id)}>
                    <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"> </span>
                    &nbsp;
                    Excluir
                </button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    );
};
```

now my smart components:

***src/containers/UserList.js***

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import User from '../components/User';
import { deleteUser, updateCurrentUser } from '../actions/user';
import NewUser from '../components/NewUser';

function UserList({ users, onDelete, onEditUser }) {
    if (!users.length) {
        return (
            <div className="margin-top">
                No Users
            </div>
        )
    }
    return (
        <div className="margin-top">
            <table className="table table-striped">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">Nome</th>
                        <th scope="col">CPF/CNPJ</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {users.map(user => {
                        return (
                            <User user={user} onDelete={onDelete} onEditUser={onEditUser} key={user._id} />
                        );
                    })}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    );
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        users: state.users
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        onDelete: id => {
            dispatch(deleteUser(id));
        },
        onEditUser: (id) => {
            dispatch(updateCurrentUser(id))
        }
    };
};

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(UserList, NewUser);
```

***src/containers/CreateUser.js***

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { createUser, updateUser } from '../actions/user';
import NewUser from '../components/NewUser';

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        onAddUser: user => {
            dispatch(createUser(user));
        },
        onEdit: (id, name, cpfcnpj) => {
            dispatch(updateUser(id, name, cpfcnpj))
        }
    };
};

export default connect(
    null,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(NewUser);
```

[image]

***src/App.js***

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import CreateUser from './containers/CreateUser';
import UserList from './containers/UserList';
import './css/main.css'

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <h1 className="styles-app">Usuários</h1>
        <div className="row styles-app">
          <div className="col-md-12">
            <CreateUser />
          </div>
          <div className="col-md-12">
            <UserList />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: could you please show the component which renders both the form and the table. There are couple of ways of doing it depending on the behavior of update of user. What do you mean by updata here ? is it changing something in state or opening up a modal

Comment: I want to put the value of the list, in the form to update, not using the modal, just using the form already exists, in case, I would like at the moment I click edit, pick the value of list item, and put in the form to update, as in the second image

Comment: When you click your edit button, is the handleUserUpdate function updating your state in NewUser.js properly?

Comment: Sorry, handleUserChange function.

Comment: No, this is a function I created to test if the store is running, but that's almost it, I do not know how to handle this function in the button's list UserList.js and move to the form NewUser.js since there are two different components

Comment: In containers/UserList.js you have mapStateToProps bringing in user data and passing it to NewUser.js it looks like. If you log this.props.users in NewUsers.js are the users passed in?

Comment: The users come undefined, I think the way I connect is wrong, I tried to connect to components to UserList but I don't know if is this possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is something you might try. Connect your `NewUser.js` to the store.

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux;
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(NewUser);
```

Then map your currentUser state to props.

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
return {
    currentUser: state.currentUser
  };
};
```

In your `currentUserReducer`

```
initialState = {
  //Assuming these are the only values in response
  id: '',
  name: '',
  cpfcnpj: '',
  isEdit: false
};

export default function userReducer(state = initialState, action) {
switch (action.type) {
    case UPDATE_CURRENT_USER:
        return {
          ...state,
          id: action.currentUser.id,
          name: action.currentUser.name,
          cpfcnpj: action.currentUser.cpfcnpj,
          isEdit: true
        };
    default: 
        return state;
  }
}
```

You should have access to the current user object now in props.

Then in your input value field

```
value={this.props.currentUser.name}
value={this.props.currentUser.cpfcnpj}
```

You may also need to do a check to see if these values have been updated. Also, not sure if the `placeholder` text might interfere.

Hope this gets you closer to the solution.

**Edit**

In the case of clearing props, you might just add another action to do so.
In your actions for currentUser:

```
export const clearUserData = () => {
return {
    type: CLEAR_USER_DATA,
  }
}
```

And in your reducer:

```
export default function userReducer(state = initialState, action) {
switch (action.type) {
case UPDATE_CURRENT_USER:
    return {
      ...state,
      id: action.currentUser.id,
      name: action.currentUser.name,
      cpfcnpj: action.currentUser.cpfcnpj,
      isEdit: true
    };
case CLEAR_USER_DATA:
  return {
      ...state,
      id: '',
      name: '',
      cpfcnpj: '',
      isEdit: false
    };
default: 
    return state;
 }
}
```

Add the clearUserData action to execute after you submit your edits and it should reset your reducer. You might even be able to just do

```
return {
  ...state,
  initialState
};
```

Comment: It worked partially, I was able to use the value of currentUser as props in the component, now I have one more question, how can I pass the action of the edit button on UserList, to change the state isEdit of the NewUser component to true when we have the value of currentUser

Comment: I edited the answer. Look at the reducer. I added the id and isEdit key value pairs. You should be able to use `this.props.currentUser.isEdit` instead of `this.state.isEdit`.

Comment: It worked fine, I have one more question, the moment I do the insertion, I do a reset of the state, in case I clean the fields, how could I do to clear the fields of the props? when I try to set it as an empty object, the application returns me an error saying that the props are readonly

Comment: I need to clear the props, because now the Add a new user and Edit buttons are with isEdit props, and I need to set false to isEdit once I finish editing

Comment: Added another edit. You'll have to bring in clearUserData action through mapDispatchToProps but that should do the trick.

Comment: It worked perfectly, you're amazing! I have one more thing to do, when I click in Edit table item, I want to pass the value of the props currentUser to the form, is there a way to do that?

Comment: I thought of something like this, when I clicked on the edit button, pass the values ​​from the currentUser props to the form, but I do not know how to do this because the values ​​of the form are state values, is there any way to call a function when I click edit , which sets the values ​​of state and NewUser to be the values ​​of props.currentUser?

Comment: Since the form is in NewUser.js and your props.current user are mapped from state, you don't need to have state in that component at all now. Redux is storing the currentUser info which is the same shape as the state you wanted in that component. Anything you wanted to accomplish with local state can now be handled with props.currentUser. If you're talking about the values of your input, just use currentUser props instead of local state.

Comment: I understand, and in case I add a new user, how would I do to set the value of the props in handleInputChange, since I do not have a state in my component

Comment: I see what you're saying. You can leave that there for creating new users if need be. It looks like in your handleSubmit function you use local state to add and edit users. You can still get rid of the state object because setState will create a state object with only the values inputted into your input fields. I imagine the ID is created on the server and the boolean for editing is in the store which covers those two values.